# VB Script If Statement - Opening Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vbscript

Updated Code: (Macro doesn't run)

```
    Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, xlModule, strCode

If ReportFileStatus("C:\scripts\test1.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\scripts\test1.xls", "C:\scripts\test.xls"
End If

If ReportFileStatus("C:\scripts\test2.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\scripts\test2.xls", "C:\scripts\test1.xls"
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set xlModule = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Sub to open the file
Sub OpenFile(sFile, DestFile)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = True
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Set xlModule = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

    strCode = _
        "Sub CreateFile()" & vbCr & _
        "    Columns(""A:A"").Select" & vbCr & _
        "    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft" & vbCr & _
        "    Rows(""1:8"").Select" & vbCr & _
        "    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp" & vbCr & _
        "    Columns(""E:E"").Select" & vbCr & _
        "    Selection.ClearContents" & vbCr & _
"FName = ActiveWorkbook.Name" & vbCr & _
"If Right(FName, 4) = "".xls"" Then" & vbCr & _
"FName = Mid(FName, 1, Len(FName) - 4)" & vbCr & _
"End If" & vbCr & _
"Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight" & vbCr & _
"For i = 1 To Range(""B65000"").End(xlUp).Row" & vbCr & _
"TempString = """ & vbCr & _
"For j = 2 To Range(""HA1"").End(xlToLeft).Column" & vbCr & _
"If j <> Range(""HA1"").End(xlToLeft).Column Then" & vbCr & _
"TempString = TempString & _" & vbCr & _
"Cells(i, j).Value & ""^""" & vbCr & _
"Else" & vbCr & _
"TempString = TempString & _" & vbCr & _
"Cells(i, j).Value" & vbCr & _
"End If" & vbCr & _
"Next" & vbCr & _
"Cells(i, 1).Value = TempString" & vbCr & _
"Next" & vbCr & _
"Columns(1).Select" & vbCr & _
"Selection.Copy" & vbCr & _
"Workbooks.Add" & vbCr & _
"Range(""A1"").Select" & vbCr & _
"ActiveSheet.Paste" & vbCr & _
"Application.CutCopyMode = False" & vbCr & _
        "    ChDir ""C:\RES_BILLING\Export""" & vbCr & _
        "    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName & "".txt"", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, Local:=True, CreateBackup:=False" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.WindowState = xlNormal" & vbCr & _
        "    Application.DisplayAlerts = False" & vbCr & _
"End Sub"

    xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode


    objWorkbook.Close (False)
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if file exists
Function ReportFileStatus(filespec)
    Dim fso, msg

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
        msg = "True"
    Else
        msg = "False"
    End If

   ReportFileStatus = msg
End Function
```

Original Question:

My goal is to have a VB Script run a macro in multiple excel spreadsheets.

This works great but I have one issue.

Sometimes a worksheet may not be available for a given month, this is intentional.

I would like to create an IF Statement that says if excel file is unavailable skip to next file.

So in this situation, if test1.xls is unavailable move one to the next file. I Hope that make sense. Thank you to anyone who can guide me in the right direction. Programming is not my forte.

Comment: Why not check if the file exists or not before opening it?

Comment: Also why not create one procedure to open the file instead of duplicating it?

Comment: @L42: There is no `DIR` function in `Vbscript` :)

Comment: haha my bad, already deleted it. @_@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to my comments why not check if the file exists or not before opening it? Also why not create one procedure to open the file instead of duplicating it?

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, xlModule, strCode

If ReportFileStatus("C:\scripts\test1.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\scripts\test1.xls", "C:\scripts\test.xls"
End If

If ReportFileStatus("C:\scripts\test2.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\scripts\test2.xls", "C:\scripts\test1.xls"
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set xlModule = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Sub to open the file
Sub OpenFile(sFile, DestFile)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = True
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Set xlModule = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

    strCode = _
        "sub test()" & vbCr & _
        "   msgbox ""Inside the macro"" " & vbCr & _
        "end sub"

    xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

    objWorkbook.SaveAs DestFile

    objExcel.Run "Test"

    objWorkbook.Close (False) '<~~ Change false to true in case you want to save changes
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if file exists
Function ReportFileStatus(filespec)
    Dim fso, msg

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
        msg = "True"
    Else
        msg = "False"
    End If

   ReportFileStatus = msg
End Function
```

Comment: Siddharth Rout, thank you for your response. To answer your questions, I'm trying to create this script for someone in my billing department. They will not be able to change the script so it needs to work if they have all 6 reports or only 3. I didn't create one procedure to open the file because I simply did not know how to. I tried you code above and received an error object required onobjExcel.Quit    Thank you for your help.

Comment: It opens and closes files now without error, but It's not running the macro.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: Yes, the files exist. When I run the script I watch excel open and close files very quickly but the macro is not running in them.

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code that you are using?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't copy the code completely :) You are not saving the file. See the line `objWorkbook.SaveAs DestFile`

Comment: You need to add `objWorkbook.SaveAs DestFile` after `xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode` in your code like I did.

Comment: I actually removed that intentionally as my macro exports the file in a specific format. I didn't want the original files to be overwritten. So if this VB Script runs the macro then I should be seeing files exported into the folder specified by the macro. I ran this VB Script before removing that line and the macro did not run then as well. Again thank you for your help with this.

Comment: But if you don't save it and close the file then how will you see the changes? You can specify the name of the new file and format in the code it self so that it doesn't overwrite the original file

Comment: As long as the file opens and the macro is run the macro will save the file already. I placed objWorkbook.SaveAs DestFile back into the code and even with it the formatting of the files does not change.

Comment: I just retested it and it works... the code open `C:\scripts\test1.xls` file, insert the code in the module and then saves the file as `C:\scripts\test.xls`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion I don"t just want it to insert the code I want it to execute it. I added objExcel.Application.Run "CreateFile" under xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString the macro is applied to only the first file but none of the others.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Sorry it took so long to provide a solution. It's usually not like this :( I think I can safely blame it on my evening TEA!

Answer (score 2):

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

InsertCode "C:\scripts\test1.xls", "C:\scripts\test1_upd.xls"
InsertCode "C:\scripts\test2.xls", "C:\scripts\test2_upd.xls"

objExcel.Quit

Sub InsertCode(wbPath, newPath)
    Dim objWorkbook, xlmodule, strCode

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not objWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Set xlmodule = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
        strCode = _
            "sub test()" & vbCr & _
            "   msgbox ""Inside the macro"" " & vbCr & _
            "end sub"
        xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode
        objWorkbook.SaveAs newPath
        objWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yours is more complete (and you tested!)